# Discord.py Make bot wait for reply

Tags: discord, discord.py

How can I make a command in which my bot waits for a reply from the author after typing a command?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) to wait for `on_message` event.

```py
@commands.command()
async def greet(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Say hello!")

    def check(m):
        return m.content == "hello" and m.channel == channel

    msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {msg.author}!")
```

Answer (score 4):

What Fixator10 posted returned "Channel" is undefined for me. I changed it to `"return m.content == "hello" and m.channel == ctx.channel"` and it worked