# Discord.py bot: How to make a bot respond to command only in certain circumstances?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm making a Discord bot in Python, and I want to add such a function when the bot responds to the command only in certain circumstances.

> For example:

Me: `!quiz`

Bot: Gives variants - `!a; !b; !c`

Me: Chooses variants and bot responds

- The point is that if someone uses command `!a`; `!b` or `!c` before `!quiz` command is used, bot **won't** respond. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bot.wait_for()` to wait for user response:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def quiz(ctx):
channel, author = ctx.channel, ctx.message.author
await ctx.send('Choose one:\n!a;\n!b;\n!c;')

answer = await bot.wait_for(
    "message", 
    check=lambda x: x.content.startswith('!') and x.channel == channel and x.author == author
)
if answer.content.strip() == '!a':
    # here goes your logic
```

Answer (score 2):

Going off what Mahrkeenerh said you can use wait_for() Below is an example:

```
@bot.command()
async def quiz(ctx):
    await ctx.send("A, B or C")

    try:
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel, timeout=30.0)

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("You took to long...")

    else:
        if msg.content == "A":
            await ctx.send("Correct")
        elif msg.content == "B":
            await ctx.send("Wrong")
        elif msg.content == "C":
            await ctx.send("Wrong")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Huh?")
```

We are sending a message and then waiting for a response, we are also checking to see if its the original author and the original channel. If so then we are checking if answer to see what the response is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wait_for()`:

[Discord.py Make bot wait for reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62965226/discord-py-make-bot-wait-for-reply)

Or you could have a global variable (a flag - boolean) that would mark, if you have used the `!quiz` command. Then inside the answers command, check if this global variable is `True`, if so, respond (and reset it back to `False`), else ignore.